# Parameters Matplotlib on a pie bar chart, size of percent, colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, pie-chart, subplot

I work on a global warming project and I have to show the industrial impact (humanity impact) on the environment. I decided to make a pie bar chart to explain it with DataViz. 
Actually, my visualization is quite good, the pie shows the CO2 emission of the different sector (energy, agriculture...) and a bar chart link to the energy sector which show the details of the Energy sector (transport, industries...). 
I wanted to make a good view of it, but there is some mistake :
- not labels on the pie chart (in legend I can make it but I want them on the pie)
- the size of the percent on the pie is too little...
- the size of the percent on the bar chart too little also and change the color
- put a title for the figure

The code is pretty complicated, and I don't find ticks to change those little things, I tried for 2 days... Please help.. I'm a beginner, I study this for one month,it's my first 'complicated graph' and I need some help ^^ I would like my presentation perfect.............................!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCQUE.png)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

#creation database and percent
dfEmissionsbyindusv2
df_pie = dfEmissionsbyindusv2.sum()
df_pie2 = df_pie.drop(['Year', 'Total emissions excluding LULUCF', 'Energy Industries', 'Manufacturing industries and construction', 'Transport', 'Residential and other sectors', 'Energy - Other', 'Fugitive Emissions from Fuels', 'CO2 from Transport and Storage'])


#creation figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(121)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=-0.25)

# graphe 1 : pie chart percent by sector
#labels = ('Energy', 'Agriculture', 'Waste', 'Other', 'Industrial processes and product use')
#angle = -180 * ratios[0]
ax1.pie(df_pie2, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=45, explode = (0.1,0,0, 0, 0), textprops=dict(color = "w"))
ax1.legend(('Energy', 'Agriculture', 'Waste', 'Other', 'Industrial processes and product use'))


# graphe 2 : bar chart zoom industry sector
xpos = 0
bottom = 0
ratios = [ratio1,ratio2,ratio3,ratio4,ratio5,ratio6,ratio7]
width = 1

colors = [[.1, .3, .9], [.1, .3, .7], [.1, .3, .5], [.1, .3, .3], [.1, .3, .2], [.1, .3, .2], [.1, .1, .1]]

for j in range(len(ratios)):
    height = ratios[j]
    ax2.bar(xpos, height, width, bottom=bottom, color=colors[j])
    ypos = bottom + ax2.patches[j].get_height() / 2
    bottom += height
    ax2.text(xpos, ypos, "%d%%" % (ax2.patches[j].get_height() * 100),
             ha='center')

ax2.legend(('Energy Industries', 'Manufacturing industries and construction', 'Transport', 'Residential and other sectors', 'Energy - Other', 'Fugitive Emissions from Fuels', 'CO2 from Transport and Storage'))
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.set_xlim( - 2.5 * width,  2.5 * width)

# 
theta1, theta2 = ax1.patches[1].theta1, ax1.patches[-1].theta2
center, r = ax1.patches[0].center, ax1.patches[-1].r
bar_height = sum([item.get_height() for item in ax2.patches])


# 
x = r * np.cos(np.pi / 180 * theta2) + center[0]
y = np.sin(np.pi / 180 * theta2) + center[-1]
con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(width / 2, bar_height), xyB=(x, y),
                      coordsA="data", coordsB="data", axesA=ax2, axesB=ax1)
con.set_color([0, 0, 0])
con.set_linewidth(2)
ax2.add_artist(con)

# 
x = r * np.cos(np.pi / 180 * theta1) + center[0]
y = np.sin(np.pi / 180 * theta1) + center[-1]
con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(width / 2, 0), xyB=(x, y), coordsA="data",
                      coordsB="data", axesA=ax2, axesB=ax1)
con.set_color(c ='black')
ax2.add_artist(con)
con.set_linewidth(2)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data ? Also If you just need to make this chart one time - I would make it in excel types software and be done with it. If you want to do for learning purpose - that's a different thing.

Comment: The goal is to make it in code and with matplotlib.... That is the point.. and not with excel. What do you mean by sample data ? Thanks you very much